# how to update and merge branch in netbeans?

Tags: svn, netbeans

im using netbeans with svn.

i've checked out a project and then i used "copy to..." and chose to copy the trunk to a branch. i deleted the working copy of the trunk and checked out the newly created branch into a working copy and made some changes both in the trunk and the branch.

now..how do i update the branch with the new data of the trunk and how do i merge the branch with the trunk using netbeans?

is this possible? cause with "merge to..." i could only chose to merge from a remote repository to a local folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> how do i update the branch with the
>   new data of the trunk

1. Check out the branch
2. Merge the repository trunk into the checked out branch
3. commit the branch to the repository

> how do i merge the branch with the
>   trunk

1. Check out the trunk
2. Merge the repository branch into the checked out trunk
3. commit the trunk to the repository

You can't merge two repository projects in Netbeans without making local copies.

Comment: what a shame...isnt netbeans, bad :P do you think this feature will be available in the future?

Comment: Netbeans uses the subversion client software to execute the versioning commands. So its svn merge that will only apply changes to a working copy.  You want to be able to resolve conflicts from the merge without messing up the repository.